# how do I prove that :$\lim_{x\to 3} x(3-x)= 0 $

Tags: calculus, limits

how do I prove that :$\lim_{x\to 3} x(3-x)= 0 $

Using $\epsilon -\delta$

I need to find $\delta>0$ whenever $\epsilon>0 $ such that:
$|3x-x^2|<\epsilon $ whenever $0<|x-3|<\delta$

$x|3-x|<\epsilon $ whenever $0<|x-3|<\delta$

$\equiv -x|x-3|<\epsilon $ whenever $0<|x-3|<\delta$

$ |x-3|<\dfrac{\epsilon}{-x} $ whenever $0<|x-3|<\delta$

I choose $\dfrac{\epsilon}{-x}=\delta $

$\equiv -x|x-3|<\epsilon $ whenever $0<|x-3|<\delta$

This implies
$-x|x-3|<-x\delta $ whenever $0<|x-3|<\delta$ Which should be proof.

By the way I was tempted to just plug in $x=3$ in $x(3-x)= 0 $

Comment: Why dont you use $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)g(x) = \lim_{x \to a}f(x) \lim_{x \to a} g(x)$

Answer (score 3):

$\delta$ needs to be independent of $x$, so your proof will not work. Here's a common trick that you see a lot. The pesky $x$ factor can be dealt with by bounding it away. So, let's require that

$$|x-3|<1.$$

With this, we can bound $|x|$.  Let's see how. You have

$$-1<x-3<1 \implies 2<x<4 \implies |x|<4 $$

whenever $|x-3|<1$. This implies

$$|x||x-3| < 4|x-3|.$$

Now, we might want to take $\delta =\frac{\epsilon}{4}$, but we need that $\delta$ not be bigger than 1 to ensure $|x|<4$ is still valid. So, we can take $\delta = \min\{1,\frac{\epsilon}{4}\}$. This gives

$$ |x||x-3| < 4|x-3| < 4\delta \leq 4\cdot\frac{\epsilon}{4} =\epsilon $$

whenever $|x-3|<\delta$.

Comment: We can't assume $|x| < 1$ if we're considering the limit $x \to 3$.  I suppose you meant to start with $|x-3| < 1$ instead?

Comment: $|x-3| < 8$ doesn't imply $|x| < 5$: you need $2$, not $8$, to get that effect.

Comment: You are correct. I was doing something very stupid. It should be okay now. Thanks.